# WCF Service App Service in Azure returns 502 error from one geographic location but works in another geographic location

Tags: angular, azure, wcf

I have 2 Resource Groups in Azure which are identical apart from the Locations which are in different timezones.  Each one has 2 App Services: One is an Angular app the other is WCF services.  They also have an SQL Server and database which the WCF uses. The Angular app calls the WCF services.  The applications and databases in these two resource groups are identical. One works perfectly, the other errors.

The problem is with the WCF service.  In one location calls to it result in CORS errors in the client "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://services.mydomain.com/myService.svc/rest/GetData' from origin 'https://angularapp.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

When I point the Angular App in the problem resource group to the WCF in the working one, it works.  When I point the Angular App from the working resource group to the WCF in the non-working one, I get the same errors described above.

I have pointed Postman to both WCF services.  When pointing to one in the working resource group, it correctly return data.  When pointing to the one in the non-working resource group, it returns error "502 - web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server".

I have configured the CORS "Allowed Origins" in Azure to "*" for both apps and it makes no difference.

I have tried deleting the problem WCF App service in Azure and recreating it but still have the same problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue and put the details here in case it helps someone else.  I set up the .Net profiler on Azure and there was an exception which showed me the real issue and led me to the solution.  The error was "DateTime values that are greater than DateTime.MaxValue or smaller than DateTime.MinValue when converted to UTC cannot be serialized to JSON."

The issue was caused the JSON serializer.  When a datetime in an object is serialized into json, it puts the value as DateTime.MinValue.  If your timezone is greater than GMT (which was the case with my location that didn't work), it tries to set the value as DateTime.MinValue minus how many hours ahead of GMT the timezone is.  This is invalid as you can be less than the MinValue and causes an exception.  To fix it, I had to change the DataMember attributes for all DateTime properties of objects that would be serialized to [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)].  This resolved the problem and the WCF services at both locations are now working.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because setting CORS in Azure does not work for WCF,we can implement IDispatchMessageInspector to add response headers before the service response,here is a Demo:

```
public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
           return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }
```

We need to implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface, and then implement cross-domain requests through WebOperationContext in the implementation class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute
    {
        public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Then we need to add ServerMessageLogger to the service behavior.

[image]

Finally we apply this behavior to the service.At this time, we do not need to configure CORS in Azure, and WCF services will also support cross-domain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ding but it is working in Azure with WCF.  I have 2 resource groups with the exact same code and configuration.  The only difference is one is pointing to one geographic location and the other is pointing to a different geographic location.  One is working and the other gives the CORS errors.  It must be some setting in Azure but I can't find what.  I went through everything and they seem the same.

Comment: What I mean is that configuring WCF CORS directly through Azure may not work.

Comment: If the WCF service is self-hosted, we can only solve cross-domain through IDispatchMessageInspector.